# Estimate the sample size in cross sectional study when the required sample size larger than the population in a small city

Tags: estimation, sampling, sample-size, clinical-trials, finite-population

I would like to know how to estimate the sample size in the cross-sectional study when the required sample size is larger than the population on Prevalence of vitamin Deficiency in multiple sclerosis patients in a small city, and what I can do if the required sample size is greater than the number of the population.

If there are references for that I hope if you can support me.

Comment: Could you tell us how you have determined the "required" sample size?  What are your criteria and what population characteristics did you assume to compute the sample size?

Comment: If you're sampling without replacement from a small population, then the variance goes down as the sample size increases. If you sample _everyone_ (do a complete census), then there's no probability error in the result.   // Something must be wrong with your current sample size determination,

Comment: I used the formula mentioned in this article: 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8369531/


n=Z^2×p×q/e^2,

n = required sample size,

Z = 1.645 at 90% Confidence Interval

p = prevalence of vitamin D deficiency among patients of ACS in reference population, 50%,

q = 1-p,

e = margin of error, 9%